# unable to flash esp32. the port doesn't exist

Tags: esp32

I've been trying to flash esp-wroom-32 for a long time, but I can't seem to get it. idf.py throws this error:

```
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist
CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:55 (message):
  /home/matvey/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.9_env/bin/python;;/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32
  failed
FAILED: CMakeFiles/flash /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build/CMakeFiles/flash
cd /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py && /usr/bin/cmake -D IDF_PATH=/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf -D "SERIAL_TOOL=/home/matvey/.espressif/python_env /idf5.1_py3.9_env/bin/python;;/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32" -D "SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS=--before=default_reset; --after=hard_reset;write_flash;@flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY=/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build -P /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/ esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1, output of the command is in the /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build/log/idf_py_stderr_output_27303 and /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/ examples/get-started/hello_world/build/log/idf_py_stdout_output_27303`
```

I have no idea what could be the problem, I changed the udev settings, but maybe it did not work for me.

Comment: The error message seems very clear.  Your device is not located at `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  What command line are you entering?  Are you forcing a specific port?  Usually the tool will search to find it.  You might `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` to see what devices there are.

Comment: @TimRoberts
The command I entered: "idf.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 flash".

"ls /dev/ttyUSB*" output "/dev/ttyUSB0".

Also entering the command "idf_monitor.py" showed an error: "OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'".

Comment: arduino ide sees the port and shows it as /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Serial ports are one-user-at-a-time.  If the IDE has the port open, you can't open it from your script.

Comment: Are you able to download a simple Arduino based program to your ESP32 over /dev/ttyUSB0 using your Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 39):

add yourself to dialout and change permissions on it

```
$ sudo adduser <username> dialout
$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It worked for me

Comment: If the user is added to the correct group, why would we need to add global read/write?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the file that represents the device. Although it worked for me, I found out each time the device is plugged I've to change the file mod. Probably there's a better way to do it. In no way I'm an expert I'm sharing what I found out worked for me. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: for arch-based distros it would be: usermod -a -G uucp <username>

Answer (score 2):

*this is mostly because you do not have the **necessary permission to connect though uart drivers***

*could solve it by granting permissions everytime you connect a device by*
$ **sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0**
but will again fail on reboot

*to grant permissions do this instead*

$ **lsusb**
*to identify the uart device your working with*

$ **sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER**
*to add user to the dialout group*

**sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules**

**set the rules here**

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="yyyy", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"

in this replace the xxxx and yyyy with ur deviceid and productid that you found after running lsusb

for example
for this
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge

do this
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"

then reload
**sudo udevadm control --reload-rules**

and All set

Answer (score 1):

Another thing can happen that the modem file name will be changed from `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `/dev/ttyUSB1` instead. So check the `/dev` directory for alternatives.

There is a very nice script in this answer:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/132175/152061

Answer (score 0):

Likely if you `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` you will find the permissions are for the root user and dialout group...

In this case, add yourself to dialout group like this...
`sudo usermod -aG dialout <yourUserName>`

Then logout/restart.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while setting up esp-idf on Ubunto,
i tried changing permission and all but it did not work.

this command was giving error
$ idf.py -p ttyACM0 flash

this one worked
$ idf.py -p /dev/ttyACM0 flash

### Steps to verify if esp board is detected

type, ls /dev

disconnect esp and again give same command,
find if the port is detected or not.

it will be ttyUSB0,1,2 orttyACM0,1,2

for me it was ttyACM0.

in windows it needs only COM3 (3 may be any thing) but in ubunto it needs full path.